# Rename folder according to mp3/flac tag information

Tags: windows-7, rename, tags, batch-file

I would like all **folders** in my music collection to be renamed with a date, which is tagged in the music files inside them. Basically, change

```
Dire Straits - Money For Nothing
```

in

```
Dire Straits - 1988 - Money For Nothing
```

Which soft or script can achieve that ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [MediaMonkey](http://www.mediamonkey.com/) or [MusicBrainz Picard](http://musicbrainz.org/doc/PicardDownload) which is what I use to catalog my collection it analyzes your music and tags them based on the song so you can tag items that have no information in the metadata. I dont see it on the page but it does do renaming based on tag information.

Comment: Thanks for you answer. I already own MediaMonkey but I really dislike its GUI, too heavy and memory consuming.

Comment: Can it rename folders according to tags, though ? I didn't find the option either. Maybe there's a script ?

Comment: I have not used MediaMonkey is some time so I may be mistaken but I could have swore you could with the Batch Rename function. You should check out Foobar2000 if you don't like how bulky it is that's its what I switched to for the same reason alongside MusicBrainz for tagging.

Comment: I am already using Foobar as my main music player ;) It's awesome ! I'm going to double check media monkey, thanks

Comment: For those of you who would like to do the same thing : In mediamonkey, right-click on any folder > Auto-organize (or <Ctrl>-<R>) then input `..\<Artist> - <Date> - <Album>\<Track#:2>. <Title>` and voilà !

Comment: That's really powerful ! Even better : `..\$if(<Album Artist>,<Album Artist>,<Artist>) - $if(<Date>,<Date> - )<Album>\<Track#:2>. <Title>`

Answer (score 5):

I've used various software for this type of thing in the past and have had fairly good luck with [MP3 Rename](http://www.nodesoft.com/mp3rename/).  It is extremely flexible in the number of types of rules that you can use for the rename and can include any of info from the ID3 tags.

Comment: I've just tested it; it doesn't appear you can rename **folders** according to tags. Did I just miss it ?

Comment: Yes, just start with the root directory and then add "\" between the variables to indicate the folder structure:   IE: C:\Music\[Artist]\[Album] ([Year])\[Track Number] - [Track Name].mp3

Comment: OK I just came back from work. It would work if only my ID3 tags contained the "Year" field ! Currently, I only have a "Date" field, set by foobar... One day, I will succeed ! Thanks anyway !

Answer (score 1):

Easytag is a nice cross-platform tool that can rename files per their ID3 tags.

- View, edit, write tags of MP3, MP2 files (ID3 tag with pictures), FLAC files (FLAC Vorbis tag), Ogg Vorbis files (Ogg Vorbis tag), MP4/AAC (MP4/AAC tag), MusePack, Monkey's Audio files and WavPack files (APE tag)
- Auto tagging: parse filename and directory to complete automatically the fields (using masks)
- Ability to rename files and directories from the tag (using masks) or by loading a text file

Get it from http://easytag.sourceforge.net/

Direct windows download link [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/easytag/files/easytag%20%28gtk%202%29/2.1/easytag-2.1.exe/download)